# Regex for find bold text

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to fetch the text between `**` and `**`.

This is what I am trying with:

```
/\**(.*)\**/ig
```

This is the sample string

```
** The ** *quick* ~~brown~~ fox ** jumped **
```

please ignore the space after ** and before **

As a result, I am getting the whole string fetched

Comment: Try replacing `/\**(.*)\**/ig` with `/\*\*(.*)\*\*/ig` (so a backslash before each *, as you are trying to fetch the literal * symbol twice)

Comment: are you trying to find from markdown text ?, try this [`regex`](https://regex101.com/r/n8lQ1k/1)

Comment: I want to fetch text between ** and ** from the string (Which comes from API response) and bold the detected string and update the GUI

Comment: is it not already bold in markdown format ?

Comment: No, it is not!!!

Comment: Try `\*\*[\w]+\*\*`. It's a simpler example. Test it here https://regex101.com/r/M2xp0B/1/

Comment: The marked duplicate question doesn't really address your central problem of the fact that you can't match all the instances of bold text, but without the *'s. This is because JS doesn't support the combination of the global `g` flag and matched sub-groups in the resultant array. It also doesn't support look-behind assertions, both of which would make your task easier. One trick is iterative `replace()` with a callback. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syb56j3q/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised your regex doesn't blow up with a compile issue since asterisk is a special character - it means 'zero or more' of whatever was previous. Based on your regex, you are capturing:

```
* zero or more of (nothing)
* zero or more of (nothing)
(.) any single character (in a capturing group)
* zero or more of (the previous item, 'any character')
```

What you want is, I think:

```
/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/ig
```

Thats:

```
\* the asterisk character
\* another asterisk
(.*?) anything, non-greedy (up until whatever is next in the regex)
\* the asterisk character
\* another asterisk
```

Comment: It doesn't blow up because `\**` means that it will try to match 0 or more asterisk characters.

Comment: Keep in mind that this answer also matches the text between more than two asterisks. For example in the string `"***text between triple asterisks***"` it will match `"**text between triple asterisks**"` with group 1 being `"text between triple asterisks"`.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea the original question had some missing formatting, so I couldn't see the leading backslash - it makes much more sense now why it was at least running